# Rotate around z-axis only in plotly

Tags: plot, plotly

I'm trying out **plotly** for interactive 3D plotting, and it's great, but I found the 3D rotated plots a bit annoying, since by default the rotation is around all x, y and z axes (similarly as in e.g. Google Maps).

Is it possible to **rotate** only around the z-axis and just pan the camera view up and down?

So basically now the rotation is SO(3) in Lie group terms. I'd prefer at least an option to use SO(2)*R.

Comment: how do you rotate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**May 27 2015 EDIT**

Plotly 3D graph interact in a new *turntable mode of rotation*.

We made this the default. Try it [on any 3D graph](https://plot.ly/~etpinard/3141/prestige-dataset-3d-plot/).

**Original answer**

At the moment, Plotly 3D graphs only support one mode of rotation, as you described.

That said, adding a second "simple" mode of rotation is on our short term road map.

In the meantime, I suggest using the "back to default" and "back to last save" buttons in the modebar

[image]

if ever your graph gets *lost in rotation*.

Comment: OK thanks for the info... looking forward to the simple rotation! :)